# iMac/MAcOS Mojave 10.14.6 does not accept correct password and shows red dot in the upper right edge

Tags: macos, imac, mojave, login

I cannot log on my iMac 2019 (Mojave 10.14.6) since today.
I am absolutely sure, that I use the correct password.
Everything worked properly until today, I did not change the password or install a new software.

If I type in the password, the waiting symbol pops up, stays for about 1 min and then it disappears and the regular log in page remains.
The only difference I mentioned was *a red dot in the upper right edge* (just next to the clock, see image below). There is no special message popping up.

I can use this iMac only with an user-account (the University's informatics desk keeps the admin account) and, unfortunately, the system admins will not not be available until next week...

**What I tried**

1. Booting in save mode (by pressing shift at the startup), which worked, however, the log in does still not work after restart
2. Repair by booting into single-user mode (by pressing command + S) an
   typing `fsck -yf` which returned: The volume appears to be OK.

**My questions**

1. What is the meaning of the red dot in the upper right edge of the log in screen?
2. Is there anything else I could try to find the reason of this problem or to fix it?

[image: Red dop upper right edge]

Comment: The red dot means it can't connect to the network (wifi or ethernet).

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Correct, I cannot login to the network accounts. Obviously they set up my account as an network account..
I tried solution 5 from here (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299864/not-able-to-login-using-network-account-after-upgrade-to-high-sierra) which did not help. Is there anything else I can try without admin rights?

Comment: Well, if you can get into single user mode, you may be able to create an admin account. Seehttps://apple.stackexchange.com/a/367630/44531